# Drawing icons in the middle of polygons - earth plugin

Tags: kml, polygon, google-earth-plugin

I was wondering if there is a good way to draw icons (markers) in the middle of polygons, using kml in google earth plugin.
Currently I solve this by calculating the middle, and for every polygon adding a placemark with the icon in the calculated center.
But then i have to make sure that when I remove the polygom I remove the marker also.
Is there a way to make them connected and not seperate like that?
Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your code? It is hard to know what is the best here. You could either encapsulate the placemark and polygon objects into a single object, allowing you to create custom "PlacemarkPolygons" that have their own add, remove methods, etc. Or else you could maintain some list of associations between placemarks and kml files, so you remove all placemarks that are associated with a particular kml file when it  is removed. You could even perhaps define the placemarks directly in the kml with the model data thus no calculations are needed! It really depends on what you have already.

Answer (score 0):

You could encapsulate the placemark and polygon objects into a single object, allowing you to create custom "PlacemarkPolygons" passing in any options you require. So you would have.

```
function PlacemarkPolygons(options) { 
  // your set up...
}
```

To see what I mean take a look at this "CustomOverlay" example that wraps a groundOverlay and a polygon to provide click events for the groundOverlay.

http://jsfiddle.net/2bUXQ/

Although the Google Earth API objects are different from yours, the principal would be exactly the same. You would define a custom object that wraps the two API objects that you want to associate together, along with any methods that help you to use it.